# Estimate number of solutions in the Roth's theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

There is a fundamental theorem in Diophantine approximation :

> For algebraic irrational $\alpha$ 
>   $$\displaystyle \left \lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert < \frac{1}{q^{2 + \epsilon}}$$
>   with $\epsilon>0$,  has finitely many solutions.

can we estimate number of solutions $N_{\alpha}(\epsilon)$?

for instance :

what is the upper bound of $N_{\sqrt{2}}(1)$? 
 number of solutions for $\sqrt{2}$, with $\epsilon=1$.

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \sqrt{2} - \frac{p}{q} \right \rvert < \frac{1}{q^{3}}$$

Comment: do you mean "irrational" when you say "algebraic" ?

Answer (score 2):

The extraordinary Roth’s theorem (which won the Fields Medal for Roth) is the following:

“For all **algebraic** irrational $\alpha$ and all $\epsilon \gt 0$, the inequality
$$\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|\lt\frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$ has only a finite number of solutions in rational irreducible $\frac pq$, which implies that, for all $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a constant $C(\alpha,\epsilon)$ such that $$\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|\gt \frac{ C(\alpha,\epsilon)}{ q^{2+\epsilon}}$$ for all rational $\frac pq$ with $q\gt 0$.
It is important to notice that the constant $C(\alpha,\epsilon)$ is not effective, and that this is a typical  theorem of existence. But the main fact is that **the irrational $\alpha$ must be algebraic, which is not so in the case of the transcendental number $\pi$.**

It may be pertinent to add that the [measure of irrationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\pi$ is known to be less than or equal to $7.6063$ (Salikov), and conjecturally less than or equal to $2.5$ (Alekseyev); and probably could be equal to $2$, as for irrational algebraic numbers and particularly for the transcendental $\mathrm e$, whose measure of irrationality is exactly $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, dear friend John Bentin, for your good English in edition.

Comment: @John Bentin: it is also pertinent to underline that $\epsilon$ must be strictly positive because if $\epsilon =0$ the inequality $$\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|\lt\frac{1}{q^2}$$ has infinitely many solutions according to a classical result of  Dirichlet.

Comment: I have done a bit of further minor editing.