# Finite amount of pairs (p,q) problem with $ \mid\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}\mid\leq\frac{1}{q^{3}} $

Tags: analysis, diophantine-approximation

I have no clue how to solve this one. I tried everything. Im helpfull for any tipps.

Show that their is a finite amount of Pairs (p, q) ∈ $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}$ ,so that :
$ \mid\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}\mid\leq\frac{1}{q^{3}} $

Comment: You could probably cook up a solution using the result here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899973/proving-left-sqrt2-a-b-right-geq1-3b2

Comment: "I tried everything"!!

Comment: Well i cannot figure it out

Comment: Did you look at the solution in the link that I posted?

Answer (score 3):

This is [Roth's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) with $\epsilon=1$ and $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$. A proof can be found in books on number theory, such as Ireland and Rosen's book "A classical introduction to modern number theory", or in Wolfgang Schmidt's "Diophantine approximation". The question has a long history here on MSE - see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915402/estimate-number-of-solutions-in-the-roths-theorem) and the links given there.

Comment: I understand, however is this proof from my analysis sheet and i have no clue how to attempt it, as I never had number theory

Comment: if you follow the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899973/proving-left-sqrt2-a-b-right-geq1-3b2), you do not need number theory. Actually, your question is a great motivation to finally take a lecture in number theory. It is a famous result, and a starting point for Diophantine approximation.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not intended as a complete proof, but just as a sketch of it.
 We may start with the following Lemma, due to Lagrange:

> **Lemma 1**: if $\alpha>0$ is an irrational number and $$\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2q^2}, $$
>   $\frac{p}{q}$ is one of the best rational approximations of $\alpha$; in particular, it is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\alpha$.
>
> **Lemma 2**: the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$ has a very simple structure:
>   $$\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,2,\ldots].$$
>   In particular, the convergents of $\sqrt{2}$ are given by ratios of Pell and [Pell-Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number), and by denoting with $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ the $n$-th convergent of the continued fraction we have:
>   $$ \left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|\color{red}{\geq} \frac{C}{q_n^2} $$
>   for an absolute constant $C$ close to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

The second Lemma provides a straightforward proof of the given claim.

Comment: Seems good, but i have no clue if I can use this as I havent introduced The Pell-Lucas numbers in class

Comment: @AjaxEdm: their name is not a crucial part of my proof sketch, you may simply ignore that part and exploit the general properties of continued fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}\right|=\frac{|\sqrt{2}q-p|}{q}=\frac{|2q^2-p^2|}{q|\sqrt{2}q+p|}\geq\frac{1}{q|\sqrt{2}q+p|}$$